# Documentation Details for managed Package

Tags: managed-package, documentation

I am new to process of publishing app on appExchange. I want the every fine details of logo, Banner and Video (like their dimension, quality of video, length of video etc). I have searched around this but not able to get the Exact information regarding this
Sharing your knowledge or sharing the link for same will greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the ISVForce Guide, here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/index_Left.htm#CSHID=appexchange_publish_listings_upload_content.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fappexchange_publish_listings_upload_content.htm|SkinName=webhelp

The specifics for uploading content (like logos, videos, etc.) is here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/index_Left.htm#CSHID=appexchange_publish_listings_upload_content.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fappexchange_publish_listings_upload_content.htm|SkinName=webhelp

The banner logo must be exactly 1200 x 300 pixels.

Good luck!